# Teaching mdworker some manners

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, spotlight

Ever since my SSD upgrade, I'm having troubles with my MBP Mid-2010 shutting down "randomly". To be more precise, it seems to be caused by mds/mdworker utilizing 100% of my CPU. As a fix I have disabled Spotlight indexing on my whole disk now, and the computer has been stable since then. However, I'd really prefer to still be able to search my disk if that's possible at all.

So, is there any way to each Spotlight/mdworker not to utilize all of my CPU capacity?

Comment: So just to clarify, you’re not actually certain that mdworker is the reason the system shuts down? Is there anything in Console.app or the logs that gives you a clearer picture?

Comment: No, I'm certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could throttle the specific program using AppPolice:

https://github.com/fuyu/AppPolice

However, this is usually the wrong way to go about it.

If programs using 100% CPU makes your computer shutdown, you have a hardware issue. It would be better to fix the hardware issue.

Usually a problem like the one you described means that the fans in your computer have stopped working to spec. They probably need to be cleaned or replaced.

Comment: I'll give cleaning the fans a try (I already dusted them off a while ago, but I didn't disassemble them).

Comment: I've disassembled the fan and removed some dust that was trapped in there. Even though it wasn't a lot of dust, it *did* seem to do the trick (fingers crossed).